# Import CSV (UTF-8) to Excel without formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I have code for pasting data from CSV file to Worksheet. Everyhting works fine but I am facing some problems with current solution.

Is there a way to paste data as it is without formatting? Now Excel is formatting for example `-Name` to `=-Name` so there `#Name?` errors instead of Values. Also it is formatting `215067910018` to `2,15068E+11`.

My CSV strings look like:

```
123456,"Word1","Word2","-Word3",,"Word4","Word5","00076",,"Word7","Word8"
```

After running the code `"-Word3"` looks like `#Name?` in Excel cell. Also instead of `00076` I get `76`

Here is my current code:

```
Sub GetCustomers()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    ws.Name = "Sheet1"

    Dim strText As String

    Dim file As String
    file = "L:\15\186507.CSV

    ' read utf-8 file to strText variable
   With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Open
        .Type = 1  ' Private Const adTypeBinary = 1
        .LoadFromFile file
        .Type = 2  ' Private Const adTypeText = 2
        .Charset = "utf-8"
        strText = .ReadText(-1)  ' Private Const adReadAll = -1
    End With

    ' parse strText data to a sheet
    intRow = 1
    For Each strLine In Split(strText, Chr(10))
        If strLine <> "" Then
            With ws
                .Cells(intRow, 1) = strLine
                .Cells(intRow, 1).TextToColumns Destination:=Cells(intRow, 1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
                    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False
            End With

            intRow = intRow + 1
        End If
    Next strLine

End Sub
```

---

**EDIT:**

I am able to do it while Converting Text to Columns manually. Shouldn't it also be possible by VBA? I mean set Column Data Format while `.TextToColumns`

[image]

Comment: The `TextToColumns` method specifies `TextQualifier=xlDoubleQuote`. Are things like -Name in double quotes? If there were, that problem might go away?

Comment: @CindyMeister they are in double quotes, like "-Word3". But problem still appears.

Comment: If you import using `Power Query` (*available in Excel 2010+*), it respects the double quote and imports `"-Wordn"` as a text string.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I was thinking about it but I am not sure how it will work if my CSV is constantly updating and there new rows coming. Will table be updated each time I open Workbook. I want to create VBS to run this application daily. So it is importing 2 CSV files to one Workbook, connects them together and them Exporting objects to our File Management system.

Comment: Refresh options are listed in the query Properties dialog window.  And on File Open is one of the options.  You can also use a timer.  And you could also program VBA event code if you want other triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FieldInfo, which is a parameter of TextToColumns, to specify the data type.  For example, to specify Text for Column 1 and Column 4, you would have the following...

```
.Cells(intRow, 1).TextToColumns _
            Destination:=.Cells(intRow, 1), _
            DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
            ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
            Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, _
            Comma:=True, _
            Space:=False, _
            Other:=False, _
            FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 2), Array(5, 1), _
                Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1))
```

For each pair within the array, the first number indicates the column number, and the second number the data type (1 = General; 2 = Text; etc . . .).  For more details, have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144210)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to set the format of the target cells to `Text` (works sometimes on e.g. copy operation), but that did not help either .....

Not an elegant solution, but worked for me when testing, is to correct any formulas introduced by the .`TextToColumns` operation afterwards. See below:

```
Dim cl As Range, rg As Range
```

and as part of your `strLine`Loop

```
On Error Resume Next
Set rg = .Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlFormulas)
If Err.Number = 0 Then                                      'Test if SpecialCells retuned something
    For Each cl In .Rows(intRow).SpecialCells(xlFormulas)
        cl.Value = Mid(cl.Formula, 2)                       'Get rid of the erreanously introduced "="
    Next cl
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```